# inapproximability within $1+n^{\epsilon}$

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, np-complete

I am a bit confused with the notation of an optimization problem not being approximable within a factor of $(1+n^{\epsilon})$.

What exactly does this mean?

I am confused because if I (as a user of the algorithm) can choose the $\epsilon$ then I can approximate it as good as I want (given the n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it means that there is no algorithm (drawn from some class of "nicely behaved" algorithms, which may be further specified nearby) such that this algorithm *always* finds a solution within a factor of $(1+n^\epsilon)$ of the true optimum, for an $\epsilon$ that *cannot* depend on $n$.

It is not quite clear from the wording you quote whether it means that there is *no* $\epsilon$ with a matching algorithm, or merely that there is *some* $\epsilon$ for which there is no algorithm.

Even if you had a "nice" algorithm for each $\epsilon$ (perhaps taking $\epsilon$ as an input) such that you can tune the precision as you want, this wouldn't necessarily mean that you could approximate to a fixed precision for all $n$ with "nice" behavior. Is often the case that the complexity analysis that allowed you to think of the algorithm as nicely behaved assumed that $\epsilon$ was *constant*. If you vary the $\epsilon$, the resource use of the algorithm may grow dramatically in ways that its ordinary big-O asymptotics for constant $\epsilon$ does not reveal.